# Tensor calculation: outer product

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, tensor-rank

it is given a tensor:

$T=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}\circ \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}\circ\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}\circ\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ -1
\end{pmatrix}\circ\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}$

**1) Why is it possible to write the tensot T as:**
$T=\begin{pmatrix}
2 &0 \\ 
 0& 2
\end{pmatrix} and \begin{pmatrix}
0 &2 \\ 
2& 0
\end{pmatrix}$

it is given in example that I can represent the tensor T as a sum of the outer product of vector triples and as 2 matrices. I have computed the outer product of the vector triples but I can't get the same result.
Can someone provide me detailed calculation?

**2) T=[[ABC]]**

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &-1 \\ 
1& 1
\end{pmatrix}$

$B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1 \\ 
1& -1
\end{pmatrix}$

$C=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &-1 \\ 
1& 1
\end{pmatrix}$

**How to compute A, B, C?**

Later on the p 35 (53), example 2. or on p 36(54) 2.2.1 the vectors a,b,c  are given without an explanation of how he/she competed them. In §2.2.1 it is given that "we set...." and it is all. No explanation of how they find them.

I have found examples in [Analysis of 2 × 2 × 2 Tensors](http://e-spacio.uned.es/fez/eserv.php?pid=bibliuned:mastermatavanz10&dsID=Documento.pdf), p 30 (48 in pdf file) example 1,6. In this example is given a calculation of a rank of  T and these decompostions without explanation.

Can someone help me to understand the examplle?

Comment: On page 35 (page 17 according to the printed page numbering) of your linked PDF you have the explicit formula for the outer product of three column vectors. Are you having trouble using this formula? The decomposition seems to be described on page 43 (printed 25). What exactly are your troubles with applying this?

Comment: @Arthur I have seen the formula on p 35, but I cant compute the same result as it is given in exmaple 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula on page 35 of your linked PDF (printed as page 17) gives
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}\circ \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}\circ\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{matrix}&&1&1\\&&1&1\\1&1&&\\1&1&&\end{matrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}\circ\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ -1
\end{pmatrix}\circ\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{matrix}&&-1&1\\&&1&-1\\1&-1&&\\-1&1&&\end{matrix}
$$
Adding these together (element-wise) gives
$$
\begin{matrix}&&0&2\\&&2&0\\2&0&&\\0&2&&\end{matrix}
$$
As for the decomposition of $T$, page 43 (printed 25) tells you to start with the expression
$$
T = \color{red}{\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}}\circ \color{blue}{\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}}\circ\color{green}{\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}}+\color{red}{\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}}\circ \color{blue}{\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ -1
\end{pmatrix}}\circ\color{green}{\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}}
$$
Then the columns of $A$ are simply the red columns (the first column of each of the two products), the columns of $B$ are the blue columns (the middle columns in each product) and the columns of $C$ are the green columns (the last column in each product).

Comment: As I read, I can compute A, B,C using a tensor decomposition, for example, Parafac with ALS. To compute A, Band C are fixed. My question is how to fixe B and C, if i don't know B and C at the begining?

Comment: @user36610 In this example, $A$, $B$ and $C$ were practically given to you. That's probably why the example didn't bother to actually do any calculations to find them. As far as I can see, the section of the paper that actually details how this decomposition works doesn't give any details on how one would calculate it. I don't think you are meant to think more about this example than exactly what they have given you. If you want to ask how one would calculate this from scratch, then you are more than welcome to ask about that. However, I think that would be best to do in a new post.